# imagemagick resize in relative pixels

Tags: imagemagick, resize-image

Is there a way with imagemagick to resize an image to exactly 10 pixel less than the original image, but without knowing the original image size ?

I know that for a 100x100 image

```
convert input.png -resize 90x90! +repage output.png
```

will do the trick but I would like to remove the 90x90 part with something like

```
convert input.png -resize -10x-10! +repage output.png
```

so that it can work with images that have other sizes.

Answer (score 0):

try to use subcall with something like

```
identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" image.jpg
```

Comment: what do you mean by "subcall" ? i cannot do a subshell command but would need a way to do it in the same convert sequence because it is for an animated gif pipeline